# Org latex exports $ ... $ math as \( ... \) : can this be avoided?

Tags: org-mode, latex

As the title says, inline math snippets such as `$x+1$` are replaced during org latex export by `\(x+1\)`. But, no one is writing inline math in LaTex files like this. Is there a way to tell Org to leave my dollars alone?

Context: the LaTeX file is collaborative and people are simply not used to `\(...\)` syntax.

Comment: Both $...$ and $$...$$ seems to be specific to plain TeX files - see http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/inline-math-mode/ arguments for first construct and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to for the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hack away a fix by executing the following after loading ox-latex:

```
(defun org-latex-math-block (_math-block contents _info)
  "Transcode a MATH-BLOCK object from Org to LaTeX.
CONTENTS is a string.  INFO is a plist used as a communication
channel."
  (when (org-string-nw-p contents)
    (format "$%s$" (org-trim contents))))
```

This means every LaTeX export, for all of your files, will use $$ instead of \( ). 
More portable solutions would define a new derived backend.

For instructions, see: https://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-Export-Configuration.html

Answer (score 2):

Either `@@latex:$x+1$@@` or `src_latex{$x+1$}` should work.